# TreeMap: min size for under-weight nodes

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Using TreeMap, one of my node has a very small weight, I can barely see it and even worse, I can't click on it... Is there a way to set a minimal size for those nodes with a small weight compared to the others?

I tried minWidth/minHeight on `series.columns.template` but no success... Here an example https://codepen.io/rapster/pen/MdpPxw with

```
var data = {
    "Ford": { "C-Max": 18390, "Edge": 10 }
}
```